# Importing rrd file into ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, import, arcgis-10.4

I have an something.rrd with something.img.xml and something.img.vat.dbf.

I need to import them as raster image to ArcMap 10.4.

Is this possible and if so, how can I do it?

Comment: Just try to add img file. In fact if you use arc catalog, it will show you (almost always) which files can be added to arcmap.

Comment: I dont have a img file. And catalog only sees "something.img.xml" but i can't do anything with it.

Comment: You should have IMG file since this is the (only) legitimate imagery that you can open from the information that you have given. Other files that you are talking about are all auxiliary items, namely, rrd is for raster pyramid(s), xml is metadata (or similar) and vat.dbf is attribute table of your raster once it is created in file system. ArcCatalog shows you only xml because it has numerous uses in ArcGIS.

Answer (score 1):

An [`rrd` file](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/reduced-resolution-dataset-files.htm) is *not* an image file, but a [raster pyramid](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/raster-pyramids.htm) file which accompanies the image file.  The `xml` file holds metadata - other information - about the image file, but is also not an image file.  You can only open the image if you have the actual image file, which in this case sounds like it's an `img` ERDAS IMAGINE file.

If you do not have the actual image file you will need to contact the source of the files to get them to supply the image.  Without it you won't be able to open the image in ArcMap.