# Opening National Land Cover data?

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, rrd

How do I open the National Land Cover data in QGIS 3.0? Attached is an image of the files. It looks like it's an .rrd file.

[image]

Comment: @Midavalo's answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/209446/importing-rrd-file-into-arcgis-for-desktop) may help (even though it is discussing ArcGIS). Have you tried to drag the img file into QGIS?

Comment: I just did and it loaded the image. How do I turn it into a usable vector layer now? Isn't it just an image file? When I zoom in it becomes pixelated.

Comment: In QGIs go to the Layers drop down menu, choose Add Layer, choose Add Raster Layer.  From the Poen a GDAL Supported Raster Data Source menu navigate to the .img file and add it to you map.